# Cart has nothing in Magento 2.1.2

Tags: mini-cart, magento-2.1.2

I have a problem with the cart because it has nothing options.

I can share a image:

[image]

I don't know if it is a bug to magento 2.1.2 or what, because I don't touch this part but not works.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have some js error

Comment: check your consol or log file or magento;